Youtube api shorts thumbnail in portait format
I am using youtube api V3 to retrieve video thumbnails.
For example video:  https://www.youtube.com/shorts/OGimWaDYMbs
API will return:
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OGimWaDYMbs/maxresdefault.jpg

However thumbnails are in 16/9 format
If I explore their html, I can see they use this (which is exactly what I want):
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OGimWaDYMbs/frame0.jpg

Is this documented somewhere?  I dont want my code to fail.
